# Performance Comparison: Elasticsearch vs. Solr vs. Sphinx vs Whoosh

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, solr, sphinx, whoosh

I've searched for comparison of these things but every comparison has been about search features. I want to compare their performance(speeds) for a project.

Comment: There are really not 'general' performance comparisons. The reason you can't find anything is because dont exist. The performance will vary with the exact type of data, how its setup and even the types of server. Pretty much garentee, that each product would be way faster for very specific types of search. Change the parameters even a little, and a different one might win. BENCHMARK - with your specific data. Only way to know.